# Deployment pattern for rabbitmq consumer

Tags: deployment, rabbitmq, pika

I'm looking for a pattern to upgrade consumers without a downtime.

Assuming some consumers are already running, I can deploy new consumers with the upgraded version of the code.

Then, I want to "drain" the old consumers, which means I'll let them finish the processing of currently unacked messages, but I don't want them to accept more messages afterwards.
I don't want to terminate the old consumers in the middle of message processing.

Does rabbitmq has some sort of consuming policies? So new messages won't be sent to the old consumers.

I use Python + pika client

Comment: See https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-cancel.html and https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/channel.html#pika.channel.Channel.basic_cancel

Comment: Why do you need to use the same message? Why can't you create a v2 of the message and send those to the new consumer(s)?

Comment: @JimG. I see nothing in the question about a "same message" or rerouting messages. It is just about canceling a consumer.

Comment: @LutzHorn: Look at the first sentence. The OP is looking to `upgrade consumers`. So that implies that he/she wishes to use the same message.

Comment: No. He asks for a way to let a consumer finish the work it currently is doing. Then stop. Then start a *different* consumer.

Comment: Correct. In short, I want to gracefully shutdown and update existing consumers

Comment: RabbitMQ does not differentiate between consumers , the consumer-cancel behavior is more related to changes on the server side to be gracefully communicated to the client , in your case i assume that the exchanges / queues stays the same only the consumer or the client code changes. The server cannot help you in this case since it is client agnostic . From my standpoint your consumer application should handle this perhaps through an internal command call or some config setting . RabbitMQ cannot help you in this case

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee The existing client libraries all support consumer cancel.